# Can I contribute to the Steam Monster Clicker game without playing the game?

Tags: steam-monster-game

I don't really like the Steam Monster Clicker game, but I still want to contribute something towards my 'team' to help get more sales out and team rewards (whatever those might be).

Is there any way I can contribute to the monster-clicking extravaganza, without having to constantly click on monsters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can deal damage to monsters without actually actively playing.  Just buy levels in the "Auto-Fire Cannon" skill.  This will keep you firing once per second without actually having to click anything.

At the very beginning, you won't be able to do much damage at all, and it may seem like you can't earn coins as a result.  Don't worry - you'll earn coins passively even if you do no damage, just by having loaded the game at least once per day.

Check in periodically and you can spend your accumulated coins on further upgrades, like the Advanced Targeting skill (similar to, but more powerful than the Auto-Fire Cannon).  Elemental ranks give you damage multipliers as well.  Armor is also worthwhile, as it keeps you alive longer and thus doing damage more frequently.

Comment: Will cannon upgrades affect my auto-fire cannon?  Or will they be a waste for players who aren't actively playing?

Comment: Are you talking about "Armor Piercing Round"?  The ones that increase your click damage don't do anything to the auto-fire cannon, unfortunately.